# Is there a jq wrapper for golang that can produce human readable JSON output?

Tags: json, go, jq

I'm writing a go program (let's call it foo) that outputs JSON on the Standard Out.

```
$ ./foo
{"id":"uuid1","name":"John Smith"}{"id":"uuid2","name":"Jane Smith"}
```

In order to make the output human readable, I have to pipe it into jq like:

```
$ ./foo | jq .

{
"id":"uuid1",
"name": "John Smith"
}
{
"id":"uuid2"
"name": "Jane Smith"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result using a jq wrapper that is open sourced? I tried finding some but they are usually wrapping the functionality for filtering JSON input not prettifying JSON output.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038598/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-go

Comment: So, the thing is I have the JSON response in a byte array and the schema of the JSON can vary arbitrarily so I can't necessarily unmarshal it without unnecessary hacks. I just need to print this JSON byte array in a pretty manner.

Comment: @SiddharthShukla The `json` package has support for that too: `json.Indent()`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package supports pretty output out-of-the-box. You may use [`json.MarshalIndent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent). Or if you're using [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder), then call its [`Encoder.SetIndent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.SetIndent) (new since [Go 1.7](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#encoding_json)) method prior to calling [`Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.Encode).

Examples:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{"id": "uuid1", "name": "John Smith"}

data, err := json.MarshalIndent(m, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(data))

enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
enc.SetIndent("", "  ")
if err := enc.Encode(m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WjLLth_BWk)):

```
{
  "id": "uuid1",
  "name": "John Smith"
}
{
  "id": "uuid1",
  "name": "John Smith"
}
```

If you just want to format a "ready" JSON text, you may use the [`json.Indent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Indent) function:

```
src := `{"id":"uuid1","name":"John Smith"}`

dst := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := json.Indent(dst, []byte(src), "", "  "); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(dst.String())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wYMWmXPMSX)):

```
{
  "id": "uuid1",
  "name": "John Smith"
}
```

The 2 `string` parameters to these `indent` functions are:

```
prefix, indent string
```

Explanation is in the docs:

> Each element in a JSON object or array begins on a new, indented line beginning with prefix followed by one or more copies of indent according to the indentation nesting.

So each newline will be started with `prefix`, which will be followed by 0 or more copies of `indent`, depending on the nesting level.

It becomes clear and obvious if you specify values for them like this:

```
json.Indent(dst, []byte(src), "+", "-")
```

Testing it with embedded objects:

```
src := `{"id":"uuid1","name":"John Smith","embedded:":{"fieldx":"y"}}`

dst := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := json.Indent(dst, []byte(src), "+", "-"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(dst.String())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/s4rpASv0AO)):

```
{
+-"id": "uuid1",
+-"name": "John Smith",
+-"embedded:": {
+--"fieldx": "y"
+-}
+}
```

Comment: Is there any way to have lists of basic types not linebreaked?