# Pretty JSON retrieved from response in GoLang

Tags: json, go

I retrieve JSON as GET response from and endpoint

```
response, _ := http.Get("https://website-returning-json-value.com")
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
w.Write(data)
```

It returns me a JSON value, which is OK, but it is very ugly (no indents etc.). I would like to make it pretty. I've read that there is util function like MarshalIndent which does the job, but this works for JSON object (?) and ReadAll function returns []byte, so it does not work. I read the documentation regarding encoding/json package but there's a lot of information and I got a little bit stuck/confused.

As far as I understand it should be done, I should get []byte via ReadAll function -> convert it to the JSON -> prettify it -> turn to []byte again.

Comment: There is no need to do that, unmarshal the json into structs and then marshal it if you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [`json.Indent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Indent) for this purpose. Example using it:

```
src := []byte(`{"foo":"bar","x":1}`)

dst := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := json.Indent(dst, src, "", "  "); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(dst.String())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vOnLqH4GozW)):

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "x": 1
}
```

But indentation is just for human eyes, it carries the same information, and libraries don't need indented JSON.

Also see: [Is there a jq wrapper for golang that can produce human readable JSON output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788045/is-there-a-jq-wrapper-for-golang-that-can-produce-human-readable-json-output/42788236#42788236)

Comment: Thank you, working as expected. I know it might be useless in most cases, but it is for demo purposes and I wanted to look it human readable ;) Thanks again!