# How can I form a pretty JSON from a string with backslashes?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a [Gin-Gonic REST API](https://gin-gonic.com) in [Golang](https://go.dev). Here I am trying to output users that are already registered as JSON, currently in Postman I only get that:

(You can ignore the `lastRequest`-Attribut, because it is currently always nil)

```
"[{\"id\":\"e61b3ff8-6cdf-4b23-97a5-a28107c57543\",\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\",\"email\":\"john@doe.com\",\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"token\":\"19b33c79-32cc-4063-9381-f2b64161ad8a\",\"lastRequest\":null},
```

But I want it like this:

```
[{
        "id": "e61b3ff8-6cdf-4b23-97a5-a28107c57543",
        "username": "johndoe",
        "email": "john@doe.com",
        "token": "19b33c79-32cc-4063-9381-f2b64161ad8a",
        "lastRequest": null
    }]
```

How do I manage this, I tried many things with the '[json.MarshalIndent](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent)' (from this [stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038598/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-go)), however it didn't change anything for me, what do I need to do? Because the backslashes stay no matter what I do, at most `\t` or spaces are inserted. I have also read that I have to do it as a byte array, but that didn't work for me either (maybe I did something wrong here too).

Here my current code:

```
var users []User
r.GET("/getusers", func(c *gin.Context) {
    usersArr := make([]User, len(users))
    for i := 0; i < len(users); i++ {
        usersArr[i] = users[i]
    }
        
    userJson, err := json.Marshal(testUser)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, string(userJson))
    }
})

type User struct {
    Id          string        `json:"id"`
    Firstname   string        `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname    string        `json:"lastname"`
    Email       string        `json:"email"`
    Username    string        `json:"username"`
    Token       string        `json:"token"`
    LastRequest []lastRequest `json:"lastRequest"`
}
```

Comment: c.JSON does the encoding for you, so you are double encoding by calling json.Marshal.

Comment: @Peter Yes I noticed that too, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this would be my first answer in stackoverflow, hope this helps.

Go gin framework comes with a few handy functions, since I've got no idea what version of golang nor Gin Framework you're using you could try this:

```
var users []User
r.GET("/getusers", func(c *gin.Context) {
    usersArr := make([]User, len(users))
    for i := 0; i < len(users); i++ {
        usersArr[i] = users[i]
    }
        
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, users)
// If Indentation is required you could try:
        c.IndentedJSON(200, users)
    }
})

type User struct {
    Id          string        `json:"id"`
    Firstname   string        `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname    string        `json:"lastname"`
    Email       string        `json:"email"`
    Username    string        `json:"username"`
    Token       string        `json:"token"`
    LastRequest []lastRequest `json:"lastRequest"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The "backslashes" are just escape characters. They aren't literally there.
2. Indenting JSON is a simple matter of calling the appropriate Indent function:

If you have the JSON string already, use the [`json.Indent`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Indent) function from the `encoding/json` package:

```golang
input := []byte("[{\"id\":\"e61b3ff8-6cdf-4b23-97a5-a28107c57543\",\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\",\"email\":\"john@doe.com\",\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"token\":\"19b33c79-32cc-4063-9381-f2b64161ad8a\",\"lastRequest\":null}]")
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := json.Indent(buf, input, "", "\t"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/kKSOkLYp7yq)

However, if you're trying to marshal directly into the indented form, just use the [`MarshalIndent`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#MarshalIndent) function intead of `Marshal`:

```golang
    userJson, err := json.MarshalIndent(testUser, "", "\t")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tested both options but it does not work for me. 
Option 1

```usersArr := make([]User, len(users))
userJson, err := json.Marshal(usersArr)
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := json.Indent(buf, userJson, "", "\t"); err != nil {
 // err
} else {
 c.JSON(200, buf.String())
}```

Option 2

```usersArr := make([]User, len(users))
userJson2, err := json.MarshalIndent(usersArr, "", "\t")
if err != nil {
 // err
} else {
 c.JSON(200, string(userJson2))
}```

Result 1 + 2

`"[\n\t{\n\t\t\"id\": \"db848d0e-8f7f-434f-bf6d-fd9085c9c86f\ ...`

Comment: In the console the JSON is formatted pretty, but in postman there is the same problem. 
```userJson, err := json.Marshal(usersArr)
  input := []byte(userJson)
  if err != nil {
   c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error-name": "userArray is empty (nil)", "error-message": err.Error()})
  } else {
   buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
   if err := json.Indent(buf, input, "", "\t"); err != nil {
    c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
   }
   c.JSON(200, buf.String())
   fmt.Println(buf.String())
  }```

Comment: That shows that it is working.  The `\t` characters are tabs.

Comment: But why is it not formatted when I make a request with postman or curl? It is only formatted when it is directly output to the console, but I would need it in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this function helps.

```
import (
"encoding/json"
"strings"
)

func logRequest(log *logrus.Entry, data []byte) {
        cp := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})
        if err := json.Compact(cp, data); err == nil {
            log.Info("Request received: ", string(cp.Bytes()))
        } else {
            stringifiedData := strings.Replace(string(data[:]), "\n", "", -1)
            stringifiedData = strings.Replace(stringifiedData, "\r\n", "", -1)
            stringifiedData = strings.Replace(stringifiedData, "\t", "", -1)
            log.Info("Request received: ", strings.ReplaceAll(stringifiedData, " ", ""))
        }
    }
```